# Cancelled wireless Migration Assistant... best way to start over?

Tags: macos, migration, migration-assistant

I was using the [Migration Assistant utility](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3231) to transfer data from my old MacBook Pro to my new Mac.  I didn't anticipate issues using Wi-Fi, but the transfer of 250 GB of data using wasn't going to end within a day of starting, so I interrupted it and I intend on starting over using a wired network (or [target mode disk connection](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH10725)) to speed the transfer.

However, now it says my HD on the new one has 60 GB occupied and I dont know where this exists. My created account has no documents/apps/etc.  I want to delete this and start fresh if the software won't clean up an aborted transfer reliably.

What is the best way to start over?

Comment: Is the goal to return the new MBA to factory state?

Answer (score 1):

If the destination MBP is brand new, save yourself some trouble, restore it from factory and run the Migration Assistant again.

However you can probably run it again and everything should be ok, it really depends what you have and what has been copied. Check /Library/ and ~/Library (use the Terminal), for example if you had GarageBand or Garage Band Jam Packs, those may have been partially copied.

I did that when I brought an MBAir. It was taking so much that I aborted, cloned my other Mac's drive and used a USB drive to do the migration.

Answer (score 0):

The Mac will intelligently continue where it left off on the Migration Assistant. You do not need to worry about removing any duplicate files.

Comment: It seems some people are seeing different results. Could this be something you have an idea where to look ? http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/55135/how-to-delete-leftover-files-from-aborted-migrations